# VS Emulator for Android is missing in official release of VS Community 2015

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, emulation

Got excited and installed VS Community 2015 immediately after the official release. But I see no VS emulator. There wasn't a secondary installation popping up as it was in preview version.

The standalone version could not be installed either (Errors pop up saying that it could not get some components). My current Windows does not support hyper-v, but I my understanding is that it's not a must for the emulator (could be wrong).

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: the emulator are Hyper-V images, so you can't use it: "Visual Studio Emulator for Android runs as a virtual machine on Hyper-V": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for pointing me the docs! Just bought this new PC with Win 8.1 home version. Will upgrade to Pro for enabling Hyper-V

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you man!